# In Python 3, using mysql.connector, passing mysql function in insert

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using Python 3.4 and mysql.connector. I would like to to enter something like this in an insert statement:

```
st = 'insert into tbl(rate,inputDt) values(%s,%s)'
data = (rate, NOW())
cur.execute(st,data)
```

Where NOW() is the mysql function for current datetime

I can get the equivalent value by constructing a variable in Python:

```
today = date.today()
```

But how can I pass the the mysql function as above?

Comment: is there a particular reason you would need to use NOW() over getting the time in python? In terms of resource efficiency, NOW() is definitely a heavier hit

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this, but I think you can pass the MySQL function as a string.

```
st = 'insert into tbl(rate,inputDt) values(%s,NOW())'
data = (rate)
cur.execute(st,data)
```

Comment: I am afraid mysql driver would interpret it as a string and put into quotes.

Comment: Ah ok. Edited my answer: What about writing it directly in the statement? Like `'insert into tbl(rate,inputDt) values(%s, NOW())'`

Comment: Yes, this would work, but I'm not sure the OP would be okay with that - depending on the use case.